# No mostrar Hosting al enviar e-mail con PHP

Tags: php, email, hosting

Alguien sabe cómo enviar un e-mail con PHP, **sin que aparezca nuestro nombre de hosting** en el remitente de nuestro destinatario. 
Utilizo las etiquetas adecuadas para el envío y el nombre, cabeceras adecuadas, pero no encuentro cuál utilizar para que no aparezca el nombre del hosting del cuál estoy enviando el e-mail. 
Agradezco todas sus respuestas ;)

Comment: Cuando dices hosting, te refieres a lo que va despues de la @?

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres decir es que no aparezca como remitente, en este caso, tu dominio.

Comment: De hecho cuando envias con phpmailer puedes configurar el `from` con lo que quieras, no es necesario que sea con tu servidor.

Comment: No utilizo librerias, es php puro, es un script básico de envío de correo. Cuando el usuario se registra en el formulario de mi web, le llega un correo de bienvenida e info básica de mi web, en el código coloco un e-mail de mi negocio, pero cuando ellos lo reciben, si bien es cierto aparece mi e-mail como remitente, también les aparece el nombre del hosting donde tengo subida mi pag. A eso voy, cómo hago para que no aparezca el nombre de mi hosting, lo he provado con clientes correo electrónicos no comunes, y todo OK, el problema es cuando utilizo los de microsoft.